# Linq join object list with integer list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda

I have a scenario as below:

```
    Event:

public int EventId { get; set; }
public string EventName { get; set;}


MediaGallery:

public int MediaGalleryID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<int> EventId { get; set;}


List<Event> eventList = query.Event.ToList();    
List<MediaGallery> mediaGallreis = query.MediaGallery.ToList();
```

I need to retrieve a eventList that eventId exists in MediaGallery's eventID list.
Can anyone advise me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
var list = eventList
  .Where(e => mediaGalleries.Any(mg => mg.EventId.Any(id => id == e.EventId)));
```

If the `mediaGalleries` or `MediaGallery::EventId` lists are large enough you may want to consider an alternative approach.  Create a set of the possible values and query into that set directly

```
var idSet = new HashSet(mediaGelleries.SelectMany(x => x.EventId));
var list = eventList.Where(e => idSet.Contains(e.EventId));
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular task, I think query comprehension syntax would be most appropriate. If I've interpeted your question correctly, you need all events that have ids in the EventId list of any MediaQuery. Here's a Linq query that should help:

```
    var eventList = 
         (from mediaGallery in query.MediaGallery
          from eventId in mediaGallery.EventId
          join event in query.Event
          on eventId equals event.EventId
          select event)
         .Distinct()
         .ToList();
```

It's not as terse as the other options, but I'd like to present it as an alternative.

Note the use of the double from syntax, which might look strange to SQL users. If this syntax is not preferred, the following query should also work:

```
    var eventList = 
         (from event in query.Event
          where query.MediaGallery.Any(mediaGallery =>
            mediaGallery.EventId.Contains(event.EventId))
          select event)
         .ToList();
```

I prefer the first option, as this code is syntactically complex, and requires an understanding of query comprehension syntax (from, where, select), chaining syntax methods (Any), and the fact that (Contains) is supported.

Of course, all of these complexities could be replaces with other code, so choose an option that feels most natural for you. In my opinion, for even moderately complex queries, I prefer query comprehension syntax.